# Can we use Solr and Lucene both together in sitecore

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore

Sitecore 7.5 introduces support for using multiple providers in the search index.

Can we solr and lucene both in a sitecore application?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. As of Sitecore 7.5 you can have different indexes configured to use different search providers.You could, for example, have one (larger) index use Solr and some smaller indexes just run on Lucene.

Previously, you had to chose one and all your indexes ran under that provider. That limitation is no longer present.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Stephen. Could you provide me some KB or sample to implement this